# comparing date and time php

Tags: php, mysql

i need to compare two dates where if one date is greater than the other then an sql will run. this is my code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM package_transaction");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {           
        $transac_code = $row['transac_code'];
        $duedate = $row['payment_due'];

        if(strtotime($date) > strtotime($duedate))
        {
            mysql_query("UPDATE package_transaction SET `status` = 'cancelled' WHERE `payment_due` = `$duedate` AND `transac_code` = `$transac_code`");

        }

    }
}
```

but its not working. please help

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Also, "it is not working" doesn't really tell us much... on which line the code fails ? what's the error ? etc

Comment: So, what is the problem

Comment: You could always just store the payment's due-date as a unix timestamp, then you can simplify all your code to 1 line: `UPDATE ... WHERE \`payment_due\` < $currentTime`

Comment: i think the problem is the if statement. i don't know if that is the right way in comparing dates. tried error reporting but no errors

Comment: If you're not doing anything with cancelled orders just run `UPDATE package_transaction SET `status` = 'cancelled' WHERE payment_due > now();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try and use the date format before using strtotime

```
$duedate = $row['payment_due'];
$duedate = $duedate->format('Y-m-d G:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) >  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($duedate))
```

Comment: it's giving me a value of 1. what does that mean?

Comment: That means a true. This is a comparison, that results in a boolean result.